# How to rename my upload file into url in my database, then resize the upload in another page

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel-4, image-resizing

I work on a project with **Laravel 4**, I would like to **rename an upload file** into **an url in my database** and I don't know how to do so. All my validation code works well, I just need to find how to rename an uploaded file in an **url name**, then **resize (200x200)** the uploaded file in **another page/layout/form (blade.php)**.

Here's my form code (createBand.blade.php):

```
{{Form::open(array('url'=>'createBand','files' => true))}}
{{-- *****files true allow users to upload files (image/logo) that we allow to upload for the layout creerGroupe***** --}}//this is how we comment with blade laravel template

<p>
    {{Form::label('name','Name of the Band (*): ')}}
    {{Form::text('name',Input::old('name'))}}
</p>
@if ($errors->has('name'))
<p class='error'> {{ $errors->first('name')}}</p>
@endif
<br>
<br>
<p>
    {{Form::label('url_Avatar','Band Avatar: ')}}
    {{Form::file('url_Avatar',Input::old('Url_Avatar'))}}
</p>
@if ($errors->has('url_Avatar'))
<p class='error'> {{ $errors->first('url_Avatar')}}</p>
@endif
<br>
<br>

<p>
    {{Form::submit('Create your Band')}}
</p>

{{Form::close()}}
```

My file is uploaded well, but I need to **rename the filename into an url** in order to **save it in my database**. And then, **resize** the uploaded image to **200x200** format in another page/layout/form (Blade template), like we can find on Facebook's band page (if you need an example of what I would like to build in the other page/layout/form, with the resize image).

Here's my controller code:

```
    public function uploadfile() {

//*****VALIDATORS INPUTS and RULES*****
        $inputs = Input::all();
        $rules = array(
            'name' => 'required|between:1,64|unique:groupes,name',
            //"urlAvatar" is an url in database but an img on the server
            'url_Avatar' => 'min:1|image|unique:groupes,urlAvatar',
);

 //*****UPLOAD FILE (on server it's an image, on the DB it's an url*****
        $file = Input::file('url_Avatar');
        $destinationPath = 'upload/';
        $filename = str_random(32) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        //This produces a random string of length 24 made up of alphanumeric characters [a-zA-z0-9]
        //$extension =$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $upload_success = Input::file('url_Avatar')->move($destinationPath, $filename);

        // we can do a redirect with some messages that file was uploaded,
        // but we need to pass all validators before reaching to the layout default
        if ($upload_success) {
            //save in the Band table database
            Band::create($data);
            return Redirect::to('/')
                            ->with('alert_success', 'your band have been created');
        } 
        else {
            return Redirect::to('createBand')
                     ->withInput()
                     ->withErrors($validation)
                     ->with('alert_error', 'respect format image or correct errors');
        }
    }
```

My **code works well**, the band **created is registered** in my database, but I would like to register the Band Avatar on **an url format** in my database. A field in my database is created for this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've edited your question to improve the spelling and grammar, if you don't like it feel free to rollback the edit. But still, I don't understand what you want to do, what is this "url format" you're talking about ? Do you just need to have an URL for your image ? In this case, just upload your images to a public folder and the URL will be `http://server/your_public_folder/image_filename`.

Comment: @André No problem, I know I can do better for my english. Like you said I would like to rename the file like your example `http://server/your_public_folder/image_filename`. On my project, the file is in a public folder, but in order to register the file in my database, i need to find a way to rename the file in url. It's not done yet, when I create the band with the file, it's not appear in my database, because it's not an url.

Comment: I would like to generate a fully qualified URL to the given path in order to register him in my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found how it works:

In fact, I need to upload the package **Intervention image**. You can find him here: https://github.com/Intervention/image.

After, follow the redirection here: http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/laravel.
Just following the instructions for laravel:

**Installation:** 
The best way to install Intervention Image is quickly and easily with **Composer**. *Run* Composer in the **windows command prompt**.

-Require the package via **Composer** in your `composer.json`:

```
"intervention/image": "2.*"
```

Then, run Composer to install or update the new requirement.

```
$ php composer.phar install
```

or

```
$ php composer.phar update
```

Now I am able to require the vendor/autoload.php file to PSR-0 autoload the library.

**Example**

```
    // include composer autoload
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    // import the Intervention Image Manager Class
    use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;

    // and you are ready to go ...
    $image = Image::make('public/foo.jpg')->resize(300, 200);
```

The Image class also has optional Laravel 4 support.

**For Laravel integration:**
After you have *installed* **Intervention Image**, open Laravel config file `config/app.php` **and add the following lines.**

In the `$providers` array add the **service providers** for this package.

```
'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider'
```

Add the facade of this package to the **$aliases array**.

```
'Image' => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image'
```

Now the Image Class will be auto-loaded by Laravel.

**Configuration:**

By default Intervention Image uses **PHP's GD library** extension to process all images. If I want to switch to **Imagick**, I can pull a configuration file into my application by running the following artisan command.

```
$ php artisan config:publish intervention/image
```

This command copies a configuration file to `app/config/packages/intervention/image/config.php`, where I can alter the driver settings for you application locally.

If you need more information about **PHP's GD library** or **Imagick**, follow the link of getting started for laravel.

Now, here's **my controller code** to save my upload file into an URL in my database, and crop the images into 200x200 format:

```
//*****UPLOAD FILE (on server it's an image, on the DB it's an url*****
        $file = Input::file('url_Avatar');
        $destinationPath = 'upload/';
        $filename = str_random(32) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        //This produces a random string of length 24 made up of alphanumeric characters [a-zA-z0-9]
        //$extension =$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $upload_success = Input::file('url_Avatar')->move($destinationPath, $filename);
        var_dump(Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize('200', '200')->save('upload/' . $filename));

        // we can do a redirect with some messages that file was uploaded,
        // but we need to pass all validators before reaching to the layout default
        if ($upload_success) {
        //save in the Band table database
        Band::create($data);
        return Redirect::to('/')
                        ->with('alert_success', 'your band have been created');
        } 
         else {
               return Redirect::to('createBand')
               ->withInput()
               ->withErrors($validation)
               ->with('alert_error', 'respect format image or correct errors');
        }
}
```

Comment: It's a good job to see how you involved with your own post. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: what di you mean by $image ??